# I have a file with multiple sheets, and I want to create the same graph on each sheet, with based on that sheet's data

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, bar-chart

Each month, I gather statistical performance data, and this data is exported into Excel files. Each file contains data for several hundred persons, each of whom performs a certain job. There's about 10 different jobs. Each job has about 50 different metrics that are measured.

The trouble is that the jobs are performed by different numbers of people. So the horizontal axis for each chart will have a different number of names on it.

I have two problems:

1. How to determine the range for each chart on each sheet.
2. How to select each sheet in a loop to create the graph.

The structure looks like this

Multiple excel files -> Has a single data-sheet -> This sheet will first be modified to have all the performance metrics normalized -> then for each job there will be created a copy of the first sheet, then all the other jobs on that new sheet will be hidden -> then I create a stacked bar chart on each separate sheet.

I wonder if the "For Each WS" the worksheet is actually selected. And if not, how it could be fixed.
Additionally, the LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(X1Up).Row has to be reconfigured to only regard visible cells. Since I am hiding the persons I don't want to have in the Chart.

```
SUB CHARTS()

DIM LR As Long

Sheets("A").Select  
Dim ALR As Long
With ActiveSheet
ALR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End with
Sheets("B").Select
Dim BLR As Long
With ActiveSheet
ALR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each WS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
IF(WS.Name ="A") THEN
LR = ALR
End IF
IF (WS.Name ="B") THEN
LR = BLR
End IF

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
(Left:=850, Width:=1536, Top:=0, Height:=864)
.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
End With

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "! $EY$1"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$EY$2:$EY$" & LR

NEXT WS
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Dim LR As Long

    Sheets("A").Select
    Dim ALR As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        ALR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Sheets("B").Select
    Dim BLR As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        BLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'This was incorrect, was ALR instead of BLR
    End With
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        ws.Activate 'ws becomes the ActiveSheet
        
        If (ws.Name = "A") Then
            LR = ALR
        End If
        If (ws.Name = "B") Then
            LR = BLR
        End If
        
        With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=850, Width:=1536, Top:=0, Height:=864)
        .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        End With
        
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "! $EY$1"
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("$EY$2:$EY$" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Next ws
```